# Why my pyinstaller python program crashes when double-clicked and not when cmd run

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, crash, pyinstaller

I hope you can help me with this one !

I am building a standalone app from python with pyinstaller.

The app works well when I run it from my anaconda prompt. However when I run it by double clicking on it,
it crashes at line : `fig = plt.Figure(figsize=(canvas_width/100, canvas_height/100),dpi=100)`

I figured this out by printing tests before and after this line.

Here are the packages I import :

```
import sys
import platform
import os
import os.path
from os.path import dirname
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import *
from pylab import *
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString, Polygon
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
```

And here is what I get when I run pyinstaller in my anaconda prompt (as you can see I am trying to include matplotlib and tkinter in hiddenimports, but nothing changes) :

```
(base) C:\Users\Jerome\Documents\Roberto Perso\Codage\VIBRALAM V5>pyinstaller --onedir --hidden-import=tkinter --hidden-import=matplotlib GUI_PROGR4_support.py
48 INFO: PyInstaller: 4.0.dev0
48 INFO: Python: 3.7.6 (conda)
48 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0
49 INFO: wrote C:\Users\Jerome\Documents\Roberto Perso\Codage\PROGR V5\GUI_PROGRV4_support.spec
51 INFO: UPX is not available.
52 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\Jerome\\Documents\\Roberto Perso\\Codage\\PROGR V5',
 'C:\\Users\\Jerome\\Documents\\Roberto Perso\\Codage\\PROGR V5']
68 INFO: checking Analysis
144 INFO: Building because hiddenimports changed
145 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
148 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
159 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
2813 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
2900 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
2914 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by c:\users\jerome\anaconda3\python.exe
3142 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\Jerome\Documents\Roberto Perso\Codage\VIBRALAM V5\GUI_PROGRV4_support.py
3986 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook distutils from 'c:\\users\\jerome\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_find_module_path\\hook-distutils.py'.
3987 INFO: distutils: retargeting to non-venv dir 'c:\\users\\jerome\\anaconda3\\lib'
5179 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook site from 'c:\\users\\jerome\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_find_module_path\\hook-site.py'.
5180 INFO: site: retargeting to fake-dir 'c:\\users\\jerome\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\fake-modules'
6854 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook setuptools.extern.six.moves from 'c:\\users\\jerome\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-setuptools.extern.six.moves.py'.
11166 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook six.moves from 'c:\\users\\jerome\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-six.moves.py'.
17063 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook urllib3.packages.six.moves from 'c:\\users\\jerome\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-urllib3.packages.six.moves.py'.
36092 INFO: Processing module hooks...
36093 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-certifi.py' from 'c:\\users\\jerome\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
36098 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-cryptography.py' from 'c:\\users\\jerome\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
36298 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-IPython.py' from 'c:\\users\\jerome\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
36712 INFO: Excluding import 'gtk'
36717 INFO: Excluding import 'tkinter'
36721 INFO:   Removing import of tkinter from module IPython.lib.clipboard
36722 INFO: Excluding import 'PyQt4'
36727 INFO:   Removing import of PyQt4 from module IPython.external.qt_loaders
36728 INFO: Excluding import 'PySide'
36732 INFO:   Removing import of PySide from module IPython.external.qt_loaders
36733 INFO: Excluding import 'PyQt5'
36739 INFO:   Removing import of PyQt5.QtCore from module IPython.external.qt_loaders
36739 INFO:   Removing import of PyQt5.QtGui from module IPython.external.qt_loaders
36739 INFO:   Removing import of PyQt5 from module IPython.external.qt_loaders
36740 INFO:   Removing import of PyQt5.QtSvg from module IPython.external.qt_loaders
36741 INFO:   Removing import of PyQt5.QtWidgets from module IPython.external.qt_loaders
36742 INFO: Excluding import 'matplotlib'
36748 INFO:   Removing import of matplotlib.backend_bases from module IPython.core.pylabtools
36748 INFO:   Removing import of matplotlib.figure from module IPython.core.pylabtools
36748 INFO:   Removing import of matplotlib._pylab_helpers from module IPython.core.pylabtools
36749 INFO:   Removing import of matplotlib from module IPython.core.pylabtools
36749 INFO:   Removing import of matplotlib.pyplot from module IPython.core.pylabtools
36751 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-jedi.py' from 'c:\\users\\jerome\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
37856 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-jinja2.py' from 'c:\\users\\jerome\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
37871 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-jsonschema.py' from 'c:\\users\\jerome\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
37890 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-nbconvert.py' from 'c:\\users\\jerome\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
38004 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-nbformat.py' from 'c:\\users\\jerome\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
38054 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-notebook.py' from 'c:\\users\\jerome\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
40204 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pycparser.py' from 'c:\\users\\jerome\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
40205 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-shapely.py' from 'c:\\users\\jerome\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
40209 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-zmq.py' from 'c:\\users\\jerome\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
40763 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.py' from 'c:\\users\\jerome\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
40765 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-encodings.py' from 'c:\\users\\jerome\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
40832 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-importlib_metadata.py' from 'c:\\users\\jerome\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
40834 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-lib2to3.py' from 'c:\\users\\jerome\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
40868 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-matplotlib.backends.py' from 'c:\\users\\jerome\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
41348 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "GTK": ignored
    Gtk* backend requires pygtk to be installed.
41707 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "GTKAgg": ignored
    Gtk* backend requires pygtk to be installed.
41950 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "GTKCairo": ignored
    No module named 'gtk'
42310 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "GTK3Agg": ignored
    The Gtk3 backend requires PyGObject or pgi
42549 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "GTK3Cairo": ignored
    cairo backend requires that cairocffi or pycairo is installed
42921 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "MacOSX": ignored
    cannot import name '_macosx' from 'matplotlib.backends' (c:\users\jerome\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\__init__.py)
43758 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "nbAgg": added
44244 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "Qt4Agg": added
44494 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "Qt4Cairo": ignored
    cairo backend requires that cairocffi or pycairo is installed
44933 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "Qt5Agg": added
45329 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "Qt5Cairo": ignored
    cairo backend requires that cairocffi or pycairo is installed
45737 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "TkAgg": added
46055 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "TkCairo": ignored
    cairo backend requires that cairocffi or pycairo is installed
46580 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "WebAgg": added
46959 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "WX": ignored
    Matplotlib backend_wx and backend_wxagg require wxPython>=2.9
47217 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "WXAgg": ignored
    No module named 'wx'
47501 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "WXCairo": ignored
    No module named 'wx'
47894 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "agg": added
48316 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "cairo": ignored
    cairo backend requires that cairocffi or pycairo is installed
48620 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "gdk": ignored
    No module named 'gobject'
49196 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "pdf": added
49846 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "pgf": added
50277 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "ps": added
50686 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "svg": added
51087 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "template": added
51298 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-matplotlib.py' from 'c:\\users\\jerome\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
51557 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-numpy.core.py' from 'c:\\users\\jerome\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
51648 INFO: MKL libraries found when importing numpy. Adding MKL to binaries
51653 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-numpy.py' from 'c:\\users\\jerome\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
51656 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pandas.py' from 'c:\\users\\jerome\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
52512 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PIL.Image.py' from 'c:\\users\\jerome\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
52972 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PIL.py' from 'c:\\users\\jerome\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
52978 INFO: Excluding import 'tkinter'
52988 INFO:   Removing import of tkinter from module PIL.ImageTk
52990 INFO: Import to be excluded not found: 'FixTk'
52994 INFO: Excluding import 'PyQt4'
53000 INFO: Excluding import 'PySide'
53006 INFO: Excluding import 'PyQt5'
53009 INFO:   Removing import of PyQt5.QtGui from module PIL.ImageQt
53010 INFO:   Removing import of PyQt5.QtCore from module PIL.ImageQt
53010 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PIL.SpiderImagePlugin.py' from 'c:\\users\\jerome\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
53016 INFO: Import to be excluded not found: 'FixTk'
53017 INFO: Excluding import 'tkinter'
53023 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pkg_resources.py' from 'c:\\users\\jerome\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
53457 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook win32com from 'c:\\users\\jerome\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-win32com.py'.
53764 WARNING: Hidden import "pkg_resources.py2_warn" not found!
53767 INFO: Excluding import '__main__'
53772 INFO:   Removing import of __main__ from module pkg_resources
53772 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pygments.py' from 'c:\\users\\jerome\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
55849 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.py' from 'c:\\users\\jerome\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
62204 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.QtCore.py' from 'c:\\users\\jerome\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
62263 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.QtGui.py' from 'c:\\users\\jerome\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
62377 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.QtSvg.py' from 'c:\\users\\jerome\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
62765 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.QtWidgets.py' from 'c:\\users\\jerome\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
63027 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pytz.py' from 'c:\\users\\jerome\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
63197 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.linalg.py' from 'c:\\users\\jerome\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
63198 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.py' from 'c:\\users\\jerome\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
63202 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.sparse.csgraph.py' from 'c:\\users\\jerome\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
63205 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.special._ellip_harm_2.py' from 'c:\\users\\jerome\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
63206 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.special._ufuncs.py' from 'c:\\users\\jerome\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
63207 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.stats._stats.py' from 'c:\\users\\jerome\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
63209 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-setuptools.py' from 'c:\\users\\jerome\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
c:\users\jerome\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\distutils_patch.py:26: UserWarning: Distutils was imported before Setuptools. This usage is discouraged and may exhibit undesirable behaviors or errors. Please use Setuptools' objects directly or at least import Setuptools first.
  "Distutils was imported before Setuptools. This usage is discouraged "
63782 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sqlite3.py' from 'c:\\users\\jerome\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
63851 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sysconfig.py' from 'c:\\users\\jerome\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
63852 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-wcwidth.py' from 'c:\\users\\jerome\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
63859 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.dom.domreg.py' from 'c:\\users\\jerome\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
63859 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.etree.cElementTree.py' from 'c:\\users\\jerome\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
63860 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.py' from 'c:\\users\\jerome\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
63861 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-_tkinter.py' from 'c:\\users\\jerome\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
64000 INFO: checking Tree
64037 INFO: checking Tree
64049 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pythoncom.py' from 'c:\\users\\jerome\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
64380 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pywintypes.py' from 'c:\\users\\jerome\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
64699 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-win32com.py' from 'c:\\users\\jerome\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
65310 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
65511 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
65530 INFO: Including run-time hook 'c:\\users\\jerome\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py'
65538 INFO: Including run-time hook 'c:\\users\\jerome\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_pkgres.py'
65542 INFO: Including run-time hook 'c:\\users\\jerome\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_win32comgenpy.py'
65545 INFO: Including run-time hook 'c:\\users\\jerome\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_pyqt5.py'
65548 INFO: Including run-time hook 'c:\\users\\jerome\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_traitlets.py'
65549 INFO: Including run-time hook 'c:\\users\\jerome\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_certifi.py'
65553 INFO: Including run-time hook 'c:\\users\\jerome\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_mplconfig.py'
65555 INFO: Including run-time hook 'c:\\users\\jerome\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_mpldata.py'
65557 INFO: Including run-time hook 'c:\\users\\jerome\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth__tkinter.py'
65597 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
65844 WARNING: lib not found: mpich2mpi.dll dependency of c:\users\jerome\anaconda3\Library\bin\mkl_blacs_mpich2_ilp64.dll
66787 WARNING: lib not found: msmpi.dll dependency of c:\users\jerome\anaconda3\Library\bin\mkl_blacs_msmpi_lp64.dll
67101 WARNING: lib not found: impi.dll dependency of c:\users\jerome\anaconda3\Library\bin\mkl_blacs_intelmpi_ilp64.dll
67249 WARNING: lib not found: msmpi.dll dependency of c:\users\jerome\anaconda3\Library\bin\mkl_blacs_msmpi_ilp64.dll
67531 WARNING: lib not found: mpich2mpi.dll dependency of c:\users\jerome\anaconda3\Library\bin\mkl_blacs_mpich2_lp64.dll
67730 WARNING: lib not found: pgf90.dll dependency of c:\users\jerome\anaconda3\Library\bin\mkl_pgi_thread.dll
67732 WARNING: lib not found: pgf90rtl.dll dependency of c:\users\jerome\anaconda3\Library\bin\mkl_pgi_thread.dll
67734 WARNING: lib not found: pgc14.dll dependency of c:\users\jerome\anaconda3\Library\bin\mkl_pgi_thread.dll
67741 WARNING: lib not found: impi.dll dependency of c:\users\jerome\anaconda3\Library\bin\mkl_blacs_intelmpi_lp64.dll
69355 INFO: Looking for eggs
69355 INFO: Using Python library c:\users\jerome\anaconda3\python37.dll
69356 INFO: Found binding redirects:
[]
69378 INFO: Warnings written to C:\Users\Jerome\Documents\Roberto Perso\Codage\PROGR V5\build\GUI_PROGRV4_support\warn-GUI_PROGRV4_support.txt
69716 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to C:\Users\Jerome\Documents\Roberto Perso\Codage\PROGR V5\build\GUI_PROGRV4_support\xref-GUI_PROGRV4_support.html
69919 INFO: checking PYZ
69939 INFO: Building because toc changed
69940 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\Jerome\Documents\Roberto Perso\Codage\PROGR V5\build\GUI_PROGRV4_support\PYZ-00.pyz
73732 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\Jerome\Documents\Roberto Perso\Codage\PROGR V5\build\GUI_PROGRV4_support\PYZ-00.pyz completed successfully.
73800 INFO: checking PKG
73801 INFO: Building because C:\Users\Jerome\Documents\Roberto Perso\Codage\PROGR V5\build\GUI_PROGRV4_support\PYZ-00.pyz changed
73804 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg
73836 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg completed successfully.
73837 INFO: Bootloader c:\users\jerome\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-64bit\run.exe
73837 INFO: checking EXE
73841 INFO: Rebuilding EXE-00.toc because pkg is more recent
73841 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
73843 INFO: Appending archive to EXE C:\Users\Jerome\Documents\Roberto Perso\Codage\PROGR V5\build\GUI_PROGRV4_support\GUI_PROGRV4_support.exe
73856 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.
73866 INFO: checking COLLECT
237791 INFO: Building COLLECT COLLECT-00.toc
248399 INFO: Building COLLECT COLLECT-00.toc completed successfully.
```

And if it can help, I built the GUI on PAGE software.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Have u fixed the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I am using pyinstaller 3.6 and matplotlib 3.2.2 and get a similar error message when building an exe.  In my case, the application runs on my machine without issue, but when distributed to others it crashes when they try to create a plot.  I created a test file with the single line.

> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

When running pyinstaller test.py, I get the some of the same warnings including...

> C:\Users\joltman\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\spce_4\lib\site-packages\setuptools\distutils_patch.py:26: UserWarning: Distutils was imported before Setuptools. This usage is discouraged and may exhibit undesirable behaviors or errors. Please
> use Setuptools' objects directly or at least import Setuptools first.
> "Distutils was imported before Setuptools. This usage is discouraged "

> 171972 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
> 172132 WARNING: lib not found: impi.dll dependency of C:\Users\joltman\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\spce_4\Library\bin\mkl_blacs_intelmpi_lp64.dll
> 172245 WARNING: lib not found: pgc14.dll dependency of C:\Users\joltman\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\spce_4\Library\bin\mkl_pgi_thread.dll
> 172249 WARNING: lib not found: pgf90.dll dependency of C:\Users\joltman\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\spce_4\Library\bin\mkl_pgi_thread.dll
> 172255 WARNING: lib not found: pgf90rtl.dll dependency of C:\Users\joltman\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\spce_4\Library\bin\mkl_pgi_thread.dll
> 172853 WARNING: lib not found: impi.dll dependency of C:\Users\joltman\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\spce_4\Library\bin\mkl_blacs_intelmpi_ilp64.dll
> 173190 WARNING: lib not found: msmpi.dll dependency of C:\Users\joltman\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\spce_4\Library\bin\mkl_blacs_msmpi_lp64.dll
> 173445 WARNING: lib not found: mpich2mpi.dll dependency of C:\Users\joltman\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\spce_4\Library\bin\mkl_blacs_mpich2_ilp64.dll
> 173747 WARNING: lib not found: msmpi.dll dependency of C:\Users\joltman\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\spce_4\Library\bin\mkl_blacs_msmpi_ilp64.dll
> 173935 WARNING: lib not found: mpich2mpi.dll dependency of C:\Users\joltman\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\spce_4\Library\bin\mkl_blacs_mpich2_lp64.dll

Not sure if these are the root of the issue, but having a similar crash problem where the console window is destroyed with no chance to report an error message.

Comment: Can this be counted as an answer to the question?